# MS VS 2010 IntelliTrace for non-Ultimate version? Possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

I read that IntelliTrace can be used only in MS VS2010 Ultimate and for 32-bit OPs.

Is it possible to install/activcate it also in MS VS2010 **Premium** with **64-bit** OP?
How?
Didn´t found sofare anything in google. :-(

Thxs in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS 2010 SP1 adds 64-bit IntelliTrace.

However, IntelliTrace is deliberately an Ultimate-only feature (it's VS Ultimate's primary selling point); you won't be able to use it without Ultimate.

Comment: thx 4 the very fast answer.
OK, seems I have to install Ultimate - and what about the 64 bit version? is that possible?

Comment: VS 2010 SP1 adds 64-bit IntelliTrace.

Comment: Thanks SLaks for your answer!